# How to stop a Lead Assignment Rule for certain Leads?

Tags: assignment-rules

I'd like to stop Lead Assignment Rules from activating for a particular type of Lead, for example, if a Lead is from a particular Country.

What are some force.com tools I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: You can bypass assigment rule like create a checkbox called bypass in lead.In assignment rule with your criteria add like bypass = false.If you want to by pass assignment rule through trigger update bypass=true in specific lead. Let me know @R.Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Could you just set a rule in your lead assignments of "Country = X" Assign to Same User?  This more or less would bypass the Lead Assignment.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for quick reply , in my scenario I want to assign the owner for particular type of lead by apex trigger and if the lead is of other type then go for lead assignment rule.

Comment: Why not just have everything assign via Assignment rules? Why rebuild the wheel?  Are you talking about re-assignment AFTER creation? In that case a Trigger or WFR can do the job.

Comment: Yes we can do that but in my case I have to further divide the criteria based on zip code so it will take my active rules to more than 50.This is why I have made a list of zip codes with owners that need to be assigned.This will be accomplished with the help of Apex Trigger for a particular type of lead..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully bypass the lead assignment Rule with the help of workflow rule . As per the order of execution workflow comes after triggers and when we update fields of lead by workflow then triggers execute again but not Assignment rule, thus we can achieve our goal.

Thanks

Comment: ?  Assignment rules (step 8)  [run before](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) workflow rules (step 10)  so some elaboration would be nice

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be a bit tricky

1. If the Lead comes in with `DMLOptions` indicating to use Lead Assignment (such as from Marketo/Eloqua/HubSpot), then the SFDC will execute the assignment rules regardless of what you do.
2. Hence, if you have use the assignment rule 'email' checkbox, then the assignee will get notified.
3. Should no assignment rule be true, the Lead will get assigned to the default Lead owner.

To avoid the email notification to the wrong person - you will need an assignment rule that assigns the "dont use assignment rules" Lead to a queue `InterimQ`.  Then, using ProcessBuilder/workflow or trigger, reassign the Leads owned by `InterimQ` to the owner you desire.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid the assignment rules execution programmatically, you can use in the before insert:

Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false;
lead.setOptions(dmo);

Here you have the DMLoptions official doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm